# Pumping XML messages in Jmeter to ActiveMQ?

Tags: activemq-classic, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing, mq

I am new to performance testing.
In my upcoming project I have to pump XML messages to ActiveMQ through Jmeter.
How can I implement this?
Any pointers to any website would help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking at performance testing ActiveMQ, you should take a look at the [ActiveMQ Performance Module](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-performance-module-users-manual.html). There is an option `producer.msgFileName` that allows you to define a file with the message being sent.